# Has done it ; Rethink those puppies

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I am reading an article about dognapping during the pandemic. The article is from *1843 magazine*. I don't know whether I read the phrases in bold right.

> There’s anecdotal evidence that the mutt market is now softening. Several pet-store owners told me that almost everyone who thought about getting a dog during lockdown ***has done it***. And as offices reopen, “some people are ***rethinking those pandemic puppies***.”

I am not sure whether the phrase **has done it** means they finally got their own dogs?

Does the phrase ***rethinking those pandemic puppies*** mean some people are thinking about not keeping their dogs any more because they may not have as much time as they did when they worked from home.

Comment: Yes "it" refers to "getting a dog".  "rethinking those pandemic puppies" means that they are now having doubts about their decision to get a dog during the pandemic.  It doesn't say why, but I suppose your guess is feasible. Perhaps they're just too tired to walk the dog after they get home after a busy day. Who knows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally it says "everybody who though about getting a puppy has thought (or finished thinking) about getting a puppy"... that's nonsense, or a pointless tautology. So let's make the reasonable assumption that the writer wants to make sense.

"Has done it" must refer to "getting a dog".  But surely not everybody who thought about getting a dog has actually got one!  That is also ridiculous.

There's only one possible reading "almost everyone who thought about getting a dog during lockdown has either got a dog, or decided not to get a dog."

I'm reading between the lines here.  There are no grammar clues to help me reach this conclusion, but this is the only possible reading that makes sense. And I assume the writer wants to make sense.

Similarly "rethinking those pandemic puppies" must mean "thinking again if getting a puppy was a good idea". As they are unable to care for the dog while at work.

Comment: I was thinking about buying a VW, and then I did it. What is the natural interpretation of that?

Comment: I think you bought the VW.

Comment: "**almost** everyone who thought about getting a dog during lockdown has done it" and a few did not.